# React components won't render after being uploaded on github. (*works perfectly on localhost)?

Tags: reactjs, github, github-pages, react-router-v4, react-router-dom

[Localhost](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EhEJP.jpg)

React components not rendered after being uploaded on github.
Works perfectly fine on local host.

Tried removing exact before the path but nothing seems to fix it.

```
    <Route exact path="/" component={Movies}/>
    <Route exact path="/moviedetails/:movieid" name ="routename" component={MovieDetails}/>
```

https://github.com/miguelalbryan/junotechchallenge-miguel-albryan

https://miguelalbryan.github.io/junotechchallenge-miguel-albryan/

Comment: Any error messages in the console?

Comment: no error messages in both local and on github

Comment: Check package.json homepage url ... Also errors in chrome dev tools: network and console..

Comment: add more code of your route file

Comment: It loads <Header /> perfectly except for the other components. What other code can I write on my route file ?